# SQL Aggregation / Window Function for Summarizing Data

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014, window-functions

I would like to create a query to do the following but I am having trouble:

I have a DB table with the columns:

- TestYear (int, e.g. 2014)
- Date (date, i.e. set of dates in a given year)
- DailyWorstValue
- RunningValue

Primary key is TestYear + Date

I would like to get the:

- LAST RunningValue ordered by Date (i.e. the final value)
- MINIMUM WorstValue (i.e. the worst value)
- Per TestYear

This will basically be a one-row summary per TestYear. Is it possible to do this using window functions? Thank you very much in advance for any help that you can give.

Comment: you can use First_Value or Last_Value to get Last Running value and Minimum Worst Value.Per Test Year is not clear .

Comment: Thanks, so I would like something like the following:

SELECT MIN(WorstValue), LAST_VALUE(RunningValue) OVER (PARTITION BY TestYear ORDER BY Date) FROM MyTable GROUP BY TestYear

but that doesn't work

Comment: i think you must be getting RunningValue correct .what lead you partition by Test Year. you should provide sample data accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Am not sure why you need `window` function to do this just `aggregate` function will do the job for you

```
SELECT testyear, 
       MIN_DailyWorstValue = Min(dailyworstvalue), 
       RV.last_runningvalue 
FROM   db_table A 
       CROSS apply (SELECT TOP 1 Last_RunningValue= runningvalue 
                    FROM   db_table B 
                    WHERE  A.testyear = B.testyear 
                    ORDER  BY date DESC) RV 
GROUP  BY testyear, 
          RV.last_runningvalue
```